# x and Y must have the same first dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, plot, dimension, graphing

I am trying to graph the running average of the first 1,000 points of the data (number of sunspots per month). I am supposed to use Y_k=t/2r(sum from m=-r to r of Y_k+m) where r=5 and y_k is the number of sunspots. I have this so far. I have already imported all the built in functions

```
   if part == 'C':
    y = data[:,1]
    x = data[:,0]


    x_2 = x[:1000]
    y_Average_Sunspot = np.empty(1000,float) 

    y_Avg = y[:1000]
    x_Avg = x[:1000]

    y_n5 = (y_Avg)-5
    y_n4 = (y_Avg)-4
    y_n3 = (y_Avg)-3
    y_n2 = (y_Avg)-2
    y_n1 = (y_Avg)-1
    y_1 = (y_Avg)+1
    y_2 = (y_Avg)+2
    y_3 = (y_Avg)+3
    y_4 = (y_Avg)+4
    y_5 = (y_Avg)+5

    y_Average = (y_5)+(y_4)+(y_3)+(y_2)+(y_1)+(y_n1)+(y_n2)+(y_n3)+(y_n4)+(y_n5)+(y_Avg)

    y_Average_Sunspots = y_Average/10



    plt.plot(x_2,y,label='First Thousand Months',color='y')
    plt.plot(x_Avg, y_Average_Sunspot,label='Running Average', color='k')
    plt.xlim(0,1000)
    plt.ylim(0,1000)
    plt.xlabel('Time (months)')
    plt.ylabel('Number of Sunspots')
    plt.legend(loc=9)
    plt.show()
```

The problem is when I import it says that x and y need to have the same first dimension. I have checked the shape and size of every array  in this program and they are all the same.

the Full Error Trace back

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()

----> 1 ps.plot_sunspots('C')

/home/loberhel/ASTR260/HW2/plot_sunspot.pyc in plot_sunspots(part)
    111 
    112 
--> 113         plt.plot(x_2,y,label='First Thousand Months',color='y')

```
114         plt.plot(x_Avg, y_Average_Sunspot,label='Running Average',
```

color='k')
    115         plt.xlim(0,1000)

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in plot(*args,

**kwargs)
   2985         ax.hold(hold)

2986     try:

-> 2987         ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)

2988         draw_if_interactive()

2989     finally:

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.pyc in plot(self, *args,

**kwargs)

4135         lines = []
   4136 
-> 4137         for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):

4138             self.add_line(line)

4139             lines.append(line)

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.pyc in

_grab_next_args(self, *args, **kwargs)

```
315                 return

316             if len(remaining) <= 3:
```

--> 317                 for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):

```
318                     yield seg

319                 return
```

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.pyc in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    293             x = np.arange(y.shape[0], dtype=float)
    294 
--> 295         x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
    296 
    297         if self.command == 'plot':

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.pyc in _xy_from_xy(self, x, y)
    235         y = np.atleast_1d(y)

```
236         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
```

--> 237             raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")

```
238         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:

239             raise ValueError("x and y can be no greater than 2-D")
```

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

Comment: start with `plt.figure()` and call `plt.show()`. Also, try what happens if you call `plt.ion()` at the beginning. Have you verified that your lists contain data before plotting?

Comment: please post the full error traceback.